# Error loading MySQLdb module: /usr/lib64/libperconaserverclient.so.18: version `libperconaserverclient_16' not found

Tags: mysql, django, percona

I'm suddenly getting the following error on my hosted Django website:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: /usr/lib64/libperconaserverclient.so.18: version `libperconaserverclient_16' not found (required by /home1/reconess/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so)
```

The site was working fine last week, then this week (with no changes made by us), we're getting that error. I'm thinking it might be a change to the MySQL setup done by the host (perhaps some update to Percona?), but given that I have very little idea of what Percona is, let alone how Django, MySQL, and Percona interact I'm having some problems figuring out what's gone wrong and how to fix it.

The file /usr/lib64/libperconaserverclient.so.18 definitely exists.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

Same thing happened to me today on a shared server with BlueHost.  The following command did the trick.

`pip3.5 install --upgrade mysqlclient`

I just looked at your full error message and noticed you are running python2.7, so your call to pip might be slightly different.

Comment: I had just googled the error in my Django site on bluehost, came across this and it fixed it for me!  thanks! Curious to know what happened with the server... maybe Bluehost updated something. I'll shoot them an email.

Comment: This fixes the same problem with Webfaction's current upgrade from CentOS 6 to 7: I needed to move from mysqlclient 1.3.7 to 1.3.10 to make my site work again.